# Another MYSQL Issue

Tags: java, mysql

```
int rs2 = s
                    .executeUpdate("INSERT INTO hiscores (userid, playerRights, LVL, XP, 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) VALUES ('"
                            + player.getUniqueId()
                            + "', '"
                            + player.getStaffRights()
                            + "', '"
                            + player.getSkill().getTotalLevel()
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getTotalXp()
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[0]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[1]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[2]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[3]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[4]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[5]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[6]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[7]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[8]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[9]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[10]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[11]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[12]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[13]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[14]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[15]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[16]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[17]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[18]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[19]
                            + "','"
                            + player.getSkill().getExp()[20] + "')");
```

I am not sure why my code isn't working.  I'm so close!  Why am I getting an error with my syntax?  It looks correct to me?  Could anybody please help me with this?  Any help is much appreciated!

fillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfillerfiller

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20) VALUES ('0', '0', '42','3' at line 1
```

Comment: Escape columns names that are numbers with backticks.

Comment: Use preparedstatements, per the answer. Do *not* construct your statements using concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a PreparedStatement in this case to simplify this code:

```
PreparedStatement st;

st = connection.prepareStatement(""
   +"INSERT INTO hiscores (userid, playerRights, LVL, XP, " 
   +"`0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11`,`12`,`13`,`14`,`15`,"
   +"`16`,`17`,`18`,`19`,`20`) "
   +"VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

st.setInt(    1, player.getUniqueId());
st.setString( 2, player.getStaffRights());
st.setInt(    3, player.getSkill().getTotalLevel());
st.setString( 4, player.getSkill().getTotalXp());

for(int i=0; i<=20; i++){
   st.setInt( i+5, player.getSkill().getExp()[i]);
} 

st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Prepared statements also avoid SQL Injections.